# How does 省's original meaning (ocular disease) semantically appertain its nounal (1. province) and verbal senses (2. examine; 3 economize; 4. omit)?

Tags: etymology

Correct my translation, but  [省's 略說](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%9C%81) touts that

> The Jia Jin inscriptions from "屮" from "目" means that the eyes give birth to something that blocks vision. Thus you can't see clearly what is in front of them. "屮" is the first text of "grass" —  which means that what grows from the eyes, is like grass growing on the ground (Shen Pei). The original meaning is a kind of eye disease. Later, under the guise of a "province" for inspection.

But how does eye disease semantically shift to signify 1. province? Then 2. examine;  3 economize; 4. omit? Please expatiate each sense separately, and don't overlook any one.

[image]

*Oxford Chinese Dictionary* (2010) p 661.

I'm assuming that eye disease refers to [Stargardt's Disease](https://urbanoptique.ca/stargardts-eye-disease/) (pictured below) or Floaters?

[image]

Comment: "後假借為省察的「省」。" means "Later on, [this character] was borrowed to write 省 in 省察". So at least one of the modern meanings is not related to the original meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation given in the question (*eye disease*) is ultimately from [*Shuōwén jiězì*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi). The *Shuōwén* explanation is problematic, and briefly addressed in the second half of this answer.

The meanings *province* and *economise; omit* are both [phonetic loans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters), and so are not related to the original glyph.

---

### Glyph origin of 「省」

「省」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*[s]eŋʔ/**, Mandarin Pinyin: **xǐng**, *to examine; to inspect*, 省察),  was originally 「眚」, comprised of semantic [「目」 (*picture of an eye*)](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=276) and phonetic [「生」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=265) (**/*sreŋ/**, via a variation of [「屮」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=5413)). 「生」 was later graphically corrupted into 「少」.

| 時期 字體 | 字形（眚） | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) | [image: 眚] | 5 殷墟甲編 |
| [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions) | [image: 眚] | [曶鼎](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E6%9B%B6%E9%BC%8E) [集成2838](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=2838&jgwfl=) |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state)) [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image: 眚] | 語叢2.10 [郭店竹簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guodian_Chu_Slips) |
| [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) 簡 | [image: 眚] | 秦律雜抄22 [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts) |
|  | **字形（省）** |  |
| [西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [image: 省] | [易經](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Ching)8 [馬王堆帛書](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawangdui_Silk_Texts) |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 省] |  |

The meaning *inspect; examine* is given commonly in the earliest known occurrences of 「眚」, e.g. in [《甲骨文合集》11171](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=11171&jgwfl=):

[image: 甲骨文合集11171]

> 丙寅卜，㱿鼎（貞）：「王【⿱止王】（往）眚（省）牛于（敦）？」
>
> [Divination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone#Shang_divination) on the day of [*bǐngyín*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%99%E5%AF%85#Chinese), [Oracle Què](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E8%B2%9E%E4%BA%BA#%E5%B8%B8%E8%A6%8B%E8%B2%9E%E4%BA%BA) asked: "The king goes and inspects the cattle at *Dùn**?"
>
> 鼎：「王勿【⿱止王】眚牛？」
> 三月。
>
> Asked: "The king does not go and inspect the cattle?"
> 'Tis the third month.
>
> <sub>**Dùn* is the name of a geographic location. Such locations in this context are usually hunting grounds or farmlands.</sub>

---

### Brief note on the *Shuōwén* explanation

The explanation given in the question (*eye disease*) is ultimately from the [*Shuōwén jiězì*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi):

> [**《說文・目部》**](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77389&page=123)
>
> <kbd>[image: 眚]</kbd>
>
> 目病生翳也。从目，生聲。
>
> *Disease of the eye causing [corneal opacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corneal_opacity)*. From semantic 「目」 (*eye*) and phonetic 「生」 (**/*sreŋ/**).

This is based on the *Shuōwén*'s categorisation of 「省」 and 「眚」 as two different characters, when 「省」 is actually a graphically-corrupted derivative of 「眚」. The *eye disease* meaning is not actually traceable anywhere, and the meaning we have today is recorded in *Shuōwén*'s entry on 「省」 proper (note the problematic glyph origin explanation):

> [**《說文・眉部》**](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77389&page=123)
>
> <kbd>[image: 省]</kbd>
>
> 視也。从眉省，从屮。
>
> To inspect. From reduced semantic 「眉」 (*eyebrow*) and semantic 「屮」 (*sprouting plant*).

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 徐偉軒《賓組貞人貞卜事類研究》
- [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
- [小學堂](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw)

  - [字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
  - [異體字表](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/variants)